# Simple sharing file/folder to my friend

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, samba, sftp

Sometimes there is a big file you want to send to your friend, or he wants to download from you. Like movie, archive or program.
Is there any simple, command-line, unix program that is simple as 

`$ share someData.tar.gz
Sharing... 
192.168.1.123 is downloading file
Done!`

while the other person can download like:

`$ wget <myIp>
Connecting to <myIp> 
Donwloading someData.tar.gz...
Done!`

I don't want to give access to my whole PC via SSH, SCP or SFTP. 
I don't want to play with groups and permissions.
Or maybe is there any way to open SFTP server just to one file/folder ?
If there isn't such program I will write it on my own, but I don't want to write something that is already written.

Comment: what about apache webserver? if you want to share files you could make them available in the www/ folder. the person you want could download it via `get`. You could resrtict access with `.htaccess` in case you want that

Answer (score 0):

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
seems to be something I was looking for :)